# campo select con input text

Tags: php, laravel, select, input-type

hola tengo un formulario con un select la lista o las opciones se rellenan con un array mi inquietud es puedo modificar de alguna manera este select ya que como son muchas muchisimas opciones el usuario pueda escribir y asi acercarse al resultado mas facilmente?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label><?php echo trans('medical-histories.procedure_code'); ?></label>
            <select  onchange="habilitar()" data-name="procedure_code" class="form-control procedure-code-autocompletation" id="inputprocedures">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php $i =0; foreach ($procedures as $item){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"> <?php echo $item->name; ?> </option>
            <?php
            $i= $i+1;
            } ?>
            </select> 
        </div>
```

esta es la parte del formulario pero quisiera poder agregar una opcion para que el usuario pueda escribir y acercarse a la opcion vi unos ejemplos con un input type text y usaba algo como esto

```
<input type="text" name="city" list="citynames">
<datalist id="citynames">
  <option value="Boston">
  <option value="Cambridge">
</datalist>
```

pero no se como podria adaptarlo a mi codigo en php laravel 8

Comment: revisa el siguiente link https://www.gestionatuweb.net/crear-un-select-con-buscador-integrado-gracias-a-select2/.

Comment: Yo lo ejecute en mi proyecto y me funciona bien.. creo que es lo que necesitas..

Comment: Yo me inclino más por el uso de esto en tu caso: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 0):

Puedes adaptar el código que tienes para que en lugar de generar un `<select>`, genere algo parecido al código con el `<datalist>`:

```php
     <div class="form-group">
        <label><?php echo trans('medical-histories.procedure_code'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" onchange="habilitar()" data-name="procedure_code" class="form-control procedure-code-autocompletation" id="inputprocedures" list="procedure-names">
        <datalist id="procedure-names">
            <option value=""></option>
        <?php $i =0; foreach ($procedures as $item){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"> <?php echo $item->name; ?> </option>
        <?php
        $i= $i+1;
        } ?>
        </datalist> 
    </div>
```

De ese modo, sigues generando los `<option>` pero dentro de un `<datalist>` en lugar de un `<select>`, y añades un `<input>` que tenga el id del `<datalist>` en el atributo `list`.